# How to add lists of varying lengths as rows to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have oodles of lists that I need to combine into a DataFrame, each as a row. The lists are varying lengths. The column names will just be index numbers but I don't know how to dynamically generate them as needed.

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [10,22,13,4]
l3 = [2]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.loc[len(df)] = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns=list(range(len(l1))))
```

I get this error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 3)

Comment: So `l1` should be the first row, `l2` the second, and `l3` the third?

Comment: Yes. And the lists vary in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the lists directly to the `DataFrame` constructor:

```py
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [10,22,13,4]
l3 = [2]
df = pd.DataFrame([l1, l2, l3])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    0     1     2    3
0   1   2.0   3.0  NaN
1  10  22.0  13.0  4.0
2   2   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

If you *need* to append the rows one-by-one, you can you `DataFrame.append`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
for lst in [l1, l2, l3]:
    df = df.append([lst], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
    0     1     2    3
0   1   2.0   3.0  NaN
1  10  22.0  13.0  4.0
2   2   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I don't have all the lists at the same time. I generate them one-at-a-time and add them to the DF

Comment: Hmm. Do you have to do that? Appending to a dataframe is _notoriously_ slow. Could you accumulate the lists into one big list and at the end pass that to the dataframe? Or you you _have_ to append them?

Comment: Yes, I have to append them.

Comment: @nicomp check my answer :)